# Invoking Remoting IPC Channel from Powershell Remoting session

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-remoting, .net-remoting

I have the following environment configuration:

1. "Target" machine with my Windows Service running under "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM". This Windows Service has a .NET Remoting secure IPC port open like so:

   ```
       Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
       properties["authorizedGroup"] = GetUsersGroupName(); // "S-1-5-32-545" SID, setting to "S-1-1-0" gives the same result
       properties["name"] = configuration.ServiceShortName + ".Server";
       properties["portName"] = configuration.ServiceGuid;
       BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider sinkProvider = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
       sinkProvider.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
       Channel = new IpcServerChannel(properties, sinkProvider);
       Channel.IsSecured = true;
       ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(Channel, true);
   ```
2. "Caller" machine, that from a domain-authenticated account (DOMAIN\Caller) remotely invokes a **local** (local on "Target") application (let's name it TargetApp) on "Target" machine through Powershell Remoting (WS-Management):

   ```
   $session = new-pssession -computerName "$targetHost"
   Invoke-Command -Session $session -Args $application,$arguments -OutVariable output -scriptblock $scriptBlockRemote
   Remove-PSSession $session
   ```
3. The TargetApp that is invoked locally on the "Target" machine (due to the powershell remoting call from "Caller") has to make an IPC Client Call to IPC Server on the same "Target" machine (that IPC Server runs under windows service on same Target machine)
4. Any attempts to call the IPC Server in this configuration end up with :

> Failed to connect to an IPC Port: Access is denied.

Observations:

1. Changing the properties["authorizedGroup"] to "Everyone" ("S-1-1-0") during server channel initialization does not help and I get the same error. Completely disabling security on the server channel yields the same result.
2. When "Caller" invokes a TargetApp on "Target" machine I can clearly see that :

   - "C:\Windows\system32\wsmprovhost.exe -Embedding" process is started on "Target" machine under "Caller" user credentials ("DOMAIN\Caller")
   - wsmprovhost.exe on "Target" then invokes the TargetApp under "Caller" user credentials ("DOMAIN\Caller")
   - When application reaches the point of calling the IPC Server, it fails
3. Essentially I can clearly see that powershell does invoke the local TargetApp on "Target" machine under expected credentials, however for some reason the IPC call fails (although two processes - the TargetApp that does the IPC Client call and the windows service that houses the IPC Server - are on the same machine, the IPC call fails)
4. **Magically**! If I go to "Target" machine directly, run "cmd" under DOMAIN\Caller account credentials and invoke the TargetApp in this way - the IPC call succeeds!

I've tried to find the solution, and it looks like several people were bumping into this in the past, however no clear reason/cause/solution was established.

**P.S.** After a bit of research I have a suspicion that this is authentication-related, since Powershell Remoting uses Kerberos by default, while IPC channel works only with NTLM:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ms172351(v=vs.85).aspx

> The IPC channel always uses NTLM authentication. Kerberos is not supported because IPC is limited to calls within a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

So, the outcome of my investigation is as follows:

1. IPC .NET Remoting channel **only** uses NTLM, and nothing else
2. In the scenario described above the authentication is done using Kerberos

Potential solution to described scenario would be to use Windows Task Scheduler to schedule a task execution remotely.